# Get Values from a SELECT IN Statement C#

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I need to extract multiple values from a column using a SELECT statement.

[image]

```cs
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(strConn);
    MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand(

    SELECT meta_value
    FROM postmeta
    WHERE postID = 16 AND metakey IN (
    'SKU', 'Price', 'Amount'), con)

    con.Open();

    MySqlDataReader r = com.ExecuteReader();

    while(r.read())
    {
        prodMeta.Add(new ProductMeta
        {
            ProductSKU = r.GetString(0),
            ProductPrice = r.GetDouble(0),
            ProductAmountSold = r.GetInt16(0)
        }
    }
```

I am only getting the last "ProductAmountSold" for each one. I'm guessing that it's something to do with ExecuteReader which brings back the column. I've looked around and can't find any easy to follow instructions on getting multiple values from a single column using 1 query.

Comment: you are using a specific  ID `postID = 16` shouldn't  this only  return the 1 row ?

Comment: Yes, postID is for values from another table ID is the table ID.

Comment: is meta_value a commas separated list of values ?

Comment: I have updated the post to include a diagram of how the database is set out.

Comment: The postID is the ID from a separate table.

Answer (score 0):

You sql query select a single column. In order to select several columns you need to update your sql. i.e:

```
SELECT meta_value, price, amountSold
FROM postmeta
WHERE postID = 16 AND metakey IN (
'SKU', 'Price', 'Amount'), con)
```

then increment index, when you get your value:

```
    {
        ProductSKU = r.GetString(0),
        ProductPrice = r.GetDouble(1),
        ProductAmountSold = r.GetInt16(2)
    }
```

This could be helpful: [Retrieve data using a DataReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader)

Comment: They aren't from different columns though. There are 4 columns. Column 1 is table ID, Column 2 is postID and Column 3 is MetaKey and Column 4 is MetaValue. 

Meta Value contains the values for 'SKU', 'Price', 'Amount' postID is from another table.

Comment: I've updated the post with a diagram of the DB structure.

Answer (score 0):

you need to read the metakey column as well to know how to parse the meta_value column

```
SELECT metakey, meta_value
FROM postmeta
WHERE postID = 16 AND metakey IN (
'SKU', 'Price', 'Amount'), con)

con.Open();

MySqlDataReader r = com.ExecuteReader();

while(r.read())
{
    prodMeta.Add(new ProductMeta
    {
        String type = r.GetString(0);
        if (type == "SKU")
        {
            ProductSKU = r.GetString(1);
        }
        else if (type == "PRICE")
        {
            ProductPrice = r.GetDouble(1);
        }
        else 
        {
             ProductAmountSold = r.GetInt16(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't check the type within prodMeta.Add. And if I do it before that would mean that I would have to call prodMeta.Add(new ProductMeta{}); for each item and that would create a new instance of ProductMeta each time?